# Converting a timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, iso

Hey I currently have my timestamps as: "10-07-2019T19-45-12", but i want it to be in unixtime like 1562770279430 in order to use the timestamps in computations. Which functions/modules in python can be uesd to easily do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function to convert string back to the datetime object.

[Example](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/):

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08-15-27'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```